# Hold to diacritics keeps disabling itself randomly

Tags: keyboard, bug, defaults, text-input

For some reason, the feature where you hold down a letter to get the diacritics menu (to type *è*, *à*, *é* etc.) keeps turning off randomly, sometimes after a reboot. When it happens, I have to enter `defaults write -g ApplePressAndHoldEnabled -bool true` into the command line, then log out and back in for it to work again. This is incredibly annoying as I use an Italian keyboard and I need to type some characters (e.g. *È*, *ᵃ*) which aren't available on the keyboard but are needed in my language nonetheless.

One thing I noticed is that when it happens, Key Repeat turns back on in System Preferences.

OS: macOS Big Sur 11.3.1
Model: MacBook Pro 16,1 (16-inch, 2019)

Comment: È is on option shift e.  ª is on option j.

Comment: @TomGewecke Fair enough. Though some of these I use so sporadically, I would probably not memorize the keystrokes I need to enter. Holding a to get ª is much more memorable and convenient.

Comment: Agree they are inconvenient alternatives, but fixing random disappearance of the popup accent menu can be very difficult.  Have any antivirus junk like webfoot installed?

Comment: I have the same problem with macOS 11.4